# Modelo lp em txt para rodar no Gurobi

Tags: vba, txt

Criei um modelo de otimização através de uma macro, escrevendo um modelo lp em txt para rodar no Gurobi. Porém, quando rodo no Gurobi, o modelo aparece como infeasible. Alguém sabe me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

Comment: É interessante colocar algum trecho de código para ajudar os usuários a reproduzirem e a encontrarem o problema. Não precisa ser todo o código, somente o necessário.

Comment: Crie um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1186/como-criar-um-exemplo-m%C3%ADnimo-completo-e-verific%C3%A1vel), isso ajuda a pergunta a ser respondida.